# Fundamental theorem of calculus over a point of discontinuity

Tags: calculus, statistics

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be a probability over the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $X$ be a real random variable with this distribution. Consider that $m_{0}$ is a point of discontinuity of the function $\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)$. I want to compute the following:

$$\cfrac{\partial}{\partial c}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{c}\mathbb{P}(X\leq t)dt\right) (m_{0})$$.

If we take $b < m_{0}$, we know that $\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)$ is continuous and bounded in $(-\infty, b]$, then, applying the fundamental theorem of calculus we have that
$$\cfrac{\partial}{\partial c}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{c}\mathbb{P}(X\leq t)dt\right) (b) = \mathbb{P}(X\leq b)$$

My question is whether it is correct the following computing:

$$\cfrac{\partial}{\partial c}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{c}\mathbb{P}(X\leq t)dt\right) (m_{0}) = \lim_{x\rightarrow m_{0}^{-}}\cfrac{\partial}{\partial c}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{c}\mathbb{P}(X\leq t)dt\right) (x) = \mathbb{P}(X < m_{0})$$

As the integrand is continuous in $(-\infty,m_{0})$ and bounded, it may help the dominated convergence theorem or something like that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In saying that $m_0$ is a "point of discontinuity" you don't exclude the possibility that there may be other points of discontinuity.  So when you say for $b \lt m_0$, "we know that $\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)$ is continuous" you are making an additional set of assumptions.  A simple example can be given to show that integrating the probability density may produce points where the derivative you tried to describe does not exist although the integrated function is everywhere *continuous*.

Answer (score 1):

Take a simple example: $\mathbb P(X=0)=1$

Then $\mathbb P(X\le t)=0$ when $t<0$, and $\mathbb P(X\le t)=1$ when $t \ge 0$, and the discontinuity is at $t=0$

So $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{c}\mathbb{P}(X\leq t)\,dt = 0$ when $c \le 0$, and $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{c}\mathbb{P}(X\leq t)\,dt = c$ when $c \ge 0$, so this is continuous

Thus $\cfrac{\partial}{\partial c}\left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^{c}\mathbb{P}(X\leq t)\,dt\right) (b) =0$ when $b <0$, and $\cfrac{\partial}{\partial c}\left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^{c}\mathbb{P}(X\leq t)\,dt\right) (b) =1$ when $b >0$, and it is not defined when $b=0$, i.e. at the original point of discontinuity